# How to use Twimlets with Twilio Android APIs?

Tags: android, twilio

I am a beginner at Twilio with Android. Could you please help me with the relationship between Twimlets and Twilio APIs?

Actually I want to realize the "Robocall verification" - when a call comes in, I want to intercept it and play it a piece of audio, asking it to press "123" to verify whether it is called by robot.

I found `https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/menu` can directly help me. But I don't know how to use this in my Android app.

Does it mean I should build a server to run a script of twimlets, then direct the call I intercepted at my Android app to the URL of the script?

If so, after I got what the caller input(assuming he inputs "123"), how could I direct his call back to the original one, which I received at my Android app?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

If you use the Menu Twimlet you won't have to run anything on your own server.  When you define a menu item for the Twimlet you have to specify what URL you want Twilio to call when the user presses a specific number.  That URL can be another Twimlet.

So in the example below, I'm using the Menu Twimlet to difine one menu item.  If the caller presses 1, then Twilio requests a URL that uses the Message Twimlet to say something to them.

```
http://twimlets.com/menu?
    Message=Press%20one%20to%20prove%20you%20are%20not%20a%20robot
    &Options%5B1%5D=http%3A%2F%2Ftwimlets.com%2Fmessage%3FMessage%255B0%255D%3DGlad%2520to%2520know%2520you%2520are%2520not%2520a%2520robot.%2520%2520Thanks!%26&
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I'd need more info on what your seeing when you try to use the link.